# NU1608 ErrorProblem in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, entity-framework-core

I'm Making an Rest APi and i'm traying to install

```
install-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

in the Package Manager. Unfortunately this gives an error

> NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 requires
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0) but
>   version Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.2.0 was resolved.

I already tried to search for a solution of this problem but nothing helped.
I installed lower version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` in the package manager but the error keeps appearing.
Anyone Can help me please?

Comment: Could ypu please show us TargetFramework of your project? It seems your TargetFramework is netcoreapp2.1 but you're trying to install the latest version of Entity Framework that required netcoreapp2.2

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/438d143af55456a3ca8c5bd5ba6d8634.png

Comment: i have the netcoreapp2.1 but i also have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.2.0 instead of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuGet in UWP apps follows the simpler approach where only the explicit package references are shown in the Installed list, hiding indirect references.  However, this can be problematic because you can lose control over how dependencies are resolved.

To fix this problem

1. remove **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer**
2. remove **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App** (if you can)
3. add an explicit reference to **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.4** then add a reference to
4. add back in **Microsoft.AspNetCore.App**.

I had the same problem with log4net not using later packages and dragging everything down.

Comment: I can't remove  *Microsoft.AspNetCore.App* and my reference manager is null nothing appears! What to do?

Comment: If your `.csproj` file contains a PackageReference to `Microsoft.AspNewCore.App`, I think you should be able to delete it from the XML file. The SDK automatically brings it in (which is why you can't uninstall it), and if your csproj tries to reference it, there might be incompatibilities, particularly with the version.